# Can shared examples be defined after a feature in RSpec 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec2

I am using RSpec/Capybara.
I am writing shared examples in the same spec file. I want to place the shared examples after the feature as the shares examples are really long.

But if I place the shared examples below the feature, RSpec is complaining that it is not able to find the shared example. Is there any way to make it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a common practice is to define the code for your shared examples in a module and include it via the configuration. that way, you have a clear code separation and reuse.

in spec/support/xyz.rb

```
module SomeSharedExamples
  [...]
end
```

in your `spec_helper.rb`

```
config.include SomeSharedExamples
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is a year old, but wanted to mention that rspecs [shared examples](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples) are an alternative to using a normal module. Basically you define module ('concern') that can be included in any spec file using `it_behaves_like "my_concern"`

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709397/how-to-reuse-scenarios-within-different-features-with-rspec-capybara) for a good example of this in action.